# Sum array values in Google Tag Manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

I'd like to create a custom variable using custom javascript in Google Tag Manager.  This variable would return the sum of each product sku quantities for a total order quantity.  So, in the example datalayer below, I'd like to return 6.

```
dataLayer = [{
    "pageName":"confirmation",
    "pageCategory":"checkout",
    "transactionProducts": [{
        "sku":"item1",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":3,
        "currency":"USD"
    },{
        "sku":"item2",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":2,
        "currency":"USD"
    },{
        "sku":"item3",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":1,
        "currency":"USD"
    }]
}];
```

For GTM, the value has to be in the return line of the js function.  I've named the quantity variable `{{sku quantity}}`.  How can I sum the total sku quantity values into a custom variable?

Comment: Nyuens answer is indeed how it's usually done. I still want to point out that it is much preferable to have your server sum up the quantities and push the result to the dataLayer. The more you have to slice and dice and traverse arrays the slower you site will become. Not a problem with a select few custom js variables, but enough of this and your site will become bogged down by the load of your custom script, so this is something you should have an eye on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way of getting the sum through a Custom JS variable, without using a custom variable, but it would require you to modify your dataLayer to a dataLayer.push and also to add an event key, like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ecomm confirmation',
    "pageName":"confirmation",
    "pageCategory":"checkout",
    "transactionProducts": [{
        "sku":"item1",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":3,
        "currency":"USD"
    },{
        "sku":"item2",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":2,
        "currency":"USD"
    },{
        "sku":"item3",
        "price":10,
        "quantity":1,
        "currency":"USD"
    }]
});
```

Your custom JS would look something like this (change the names to suit your needs):

```
function(){
    try{
        var sum = 0;
        var tp = {{transactionProducts}};

        if (tp){
            for (i=0; i<tp.length; i++){
              sum += tp[i].quantity;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    catch(e){
    }
}
```

where `{{transactionProducts}}` is a Data Layer type variable.

You could then create an event tag, for example, that would call this Custom JS and return the sum of the quantities.